# In FBSDKCoreKit, is there a reference to get the header picture as well as profile picture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKProfile/) for `FBSDKCoreKit`, there's a pre-fab `FBSDKProfilePictureView` that contains the authenticated user's Facebook profile picture. I've implemented this and it works great.

The docs don't however show anything for the header image/banner picture. Is there a built in way to retrieve this with the SDK? Or Is there a way to do it with the graph API + Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call the Graph API to do this. I recommend checking out [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/)

Comment: In order for me to accept this as the answer, providing an example of how to implement is paramount - links change over time.